# Fitting external website in iframe of a website for desktop AND mobile

Tags: iframe, web, external

As the title says, is it possible? If the external website is responsive as well for mobile, will it transition over to mobile if it is responsive to begin with?

Are there any cons that I would have to look out for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If

1. the containing site is responsive,
2. the embedded `<iframe>` code is responsive, and
3. the **src** site is responsive

then the whole thing will be responsive.

The trick is to have responsive `<iframe>` code. For my code, see the Pen [Responsive iFrame - Base Code](http://codepen.io/alxfyv/pen/EjERqw?editors=110) at CodePen. Click the *Details* link (lower left) for notes on the markup and CSS and for citations to references.

Comment: Thank you I shall take a look at it now